# Shiny downloadhandler unnecessary big file

Tags: r, shiny, glm

I am building a `shiny` application in which you can train a model. One feature is to be able to download the model object (in this case, a `glm` object), such that the user can use it later on - outside of the application. The relevant part of my code looks as follows

```
library(shiny)
library(car)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # What parameter do you wish to estimate
  selectInput(inputId = "dependent_variable",
              label = "Select dependent variable",
              choices = c("education",
                          "vocabulary")),

  # Download button for model
  downloadButton(outputId = "download_model", label = 'Download Model')
)

server <- function(input, output){

  strip_glm <- function(cm) {
    cm$y <- c()
    cm$model <- c()

    cm$residuals <- c()
    cm$fitted.values <- c()
    cm$effects <- c()
    cm$qr$qr <- c()  
    cm$linear.predictors <- c()
    cm$weights <- c()
    cm$prior.weights <- c()
    cm$data <- c()


    cm$family$variance <- c()
    cm$family$dev.resids <- c()
    cm$family$aic <- c()
    cm$family$validmu <- c()
    cm$family$simulate <- c()
    attr(cm$terms,".Environment") <- c()
    attr(cm$formula,".Environment") <- c()

    return(cm)
  }

  reactive_glm_model <- reactive(glm(paste0(input$dependent_variable, "~."), data = Vocab))
  stripped_glm <- reactive(strip_glm(reactive_glm_model()))
  stripped_glm_summary <- reactive(summary(reactive_glm_model()))

  output$download_model <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "report.Rd"
    },
    content = function(file) {

      glm_object <- stripped_glm()
      glm_summary <- stripped_glm_summary()
      save(glm_object, glm_summary, file = file)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I use the `strip_glm()` function, because I don't want the `glm` object to be [too big and carry unnecessary](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2014/05/trimming-the-fat-from-glm-models-in-r/) stuff. It should only be able to predict. However, by stripping `glm`, `summary()` does not work anymore, therefore I'd like to return the summary as well.

So here is my problem: If I download the object, there are still some 'hidden' objects making the file too big. In this reprex, it is 16.2 MB, whereas if I load the corresponding object back into memory, I find the real object size is way less

```
load("report.Rd")
object.size(glm_object) # 22 kB
object.size(glm_summary) # 2.5 MB
```

What is going on here? In the models I am using, my data potentially has millions of rows, causing the object to be several GB's and the downloading takes ages.

---

**UPDATE**

It seems to be related to the version or underlying settings. In the above settings, where I do encounter the problem I use

```
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.2                         
year           2018                        
month          12                          
day            20                          
svn rev        75870                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
nickname       Eggshell Igloo
```

Unfortunately I am not able to update the version of R due to policy constraints

---

**UPDATE II**

It seems the problem is not related to `R` or `shiny` and not reproducible on different platforms

Comment: Also, this does not seem to be a shiny issue but instead related to glm/object size.

Comment: You might want to look at the size of the internal objects of the summary, I think the summary contains the residuals or something like that, try `lapply(glm_summary, function(x) object.size(x)`

Comment: @DS_UNI All the objects contained in `glm_summary` together, are still around 2MB. If I use the downloadHandler, the file I download is 16MB in size.

Comment: aha ok I understand your problem

Comment: For the record I just tried your code on `R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)` and `Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`, and I didn't face the same problem, in fact the Rd file is 3.7 MB, while the glm_summary size is 6.9 Mb

Comment: A colleague also tried on different versions - he also did not face the same problems. There seems to be something wrong outside R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colleague here. We run this code with RStudio Server, which seems to be causing the problem. Running the reprex with R itself (but still on the same server using the same R executable), bypassing RStudio, fixes the issue and the downloaded R object is a little over 2 MB.

No idea why using RStudio is messing things up, though.
The version used is RStudio Server (Pro) 1.2.5001-3